# How can I fix this Error: not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, server, blazor

My project has 2 part ClientSide and Server side. In Server side I have Controller that it needs query and command. I put both of them and my command has a handler but after I'd done my handler it throws a error that say: not all code paths return a value.
this is my handler:

```
     public Task<ReturnCreateDataQuery> Handle(CreateCompletedActCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var party = _dbContext.Parties.SingleOrDefault(t => t.PartyCode == request.PartyCode);
        if (party == null) throw new Exception("");

        if ((bool)request.ResonableType)
        {

            var departmentText = request.DepartmentIds.Any() ? string.Join(",", request.DepartmentIds.Distinct().OrderBy(t => t)) : string.Empty;
            var cartableActs = new List<CartableActModel>();

            var cartable = new CartableStateModel()
            {

                ClaimId = request.ClaimId,
                CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                StatusCode = (int)Enumeration.StateType.Compeleted,
                PreviouseCartableStateId = request.CartableStateId
            };

            var cartableAct = new CartableActCompleteModel()
            {
                ActCode = (int)Enumeration.ActType.CompleteCustomerData,
                ActorId = party.PartyId,
                CartableStateId = cartable.CartableStateId,
                ChangeDate = DateTime.Now,
                ClaimSubjectId = request.ClaimSubjectId,
                ClaimType = request.ClaimType,
                Departments = departmentText,
                ExpertPartyId = request.ExpertPartyId,
                ResonableType = request.ResonableType,
                SubClaimSubjectId = request.SubClaimSubjectId,
                CompletedDescription = request.CompletedDescription,
            };

            var attachments = request.Attachments.Select(t => new ActAttachmentModel
            {
                AttachmentContent = t.AttachmentContent,
                ActAttachmentId = cartableAct.CartableActId,
                ActId = cartableAct.CartableActId,
                CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                Creator = party.PartyId,
                FileExtension = t.FileExtension,
                Title = t.Title,
                MimeType = t.MimeType
            }).ToList();

            cartableAct.ActAttachments = attachments;

            cartableActs.Add(cartableAct);

            cartable.CartableActs = cartableActs;

            _dbContext.Cartables.Add(cartable); 
            _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            var cartableActs = new List<CartableActModel>();
            var cartable = new CartableStateModel()
            {
                ClaimId = request.ClaimId,
                CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                StatusCode = (int)Enumeration.StateType.Finished,

            };

            var cartableAct = new CartableActSatisficationModel()
            {
                ActCode = (int)Enumeration.ActType.SatisficationCustomer,
                ActorId = party.PartyId,
                CartableStateId = cartable.CartableStateId,
                ChangeDate = DateTime.Now,
                IsSatisfy = false,
                SatisfyLevel = "1",
            };

            var attachments = request.Attachments.Select(t => new ActAttachmentModel
            {
                AttachmentContent = t.AttachmentContent,
                ActAttachmentId = cartableAct.CartableActId,
                ActId = cartableAct.CartableActId,
                CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                Creator = party.PartyId,
                FileExtension = t.FileExtension,
                Title = t.Title,
                MimeType = t.MimeType
            }).ToList();

            var outBox = new OutBoxModel
            {
                SentType = "SMS",
                ClaimId = request.ClaimId,
                IsSent = false,
                PartyCode = request.PartyCode,
                IsCustomer = true

            };

            cartableAct.ActAttachments = attachments;

            cartableActs.Add(cartableAct);

            cartable.CartableActs = cartableActs;

            _dbContext.Cartables.Add(cartable);
            _dbContext.OutBoxes.Add(outBox);
            _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

I don't know how can I fix this error I search a lot of source but I can't understand which value should return if you know this I would thank you.

Comment: There's no part in your code that returns a type of `ReturnCreateDataQuery`.  If you do not really need to return anything. Make the function return void like this. `public Task Handle(...) `

Comment: Also, if you are returning a Task, then usually an "async" modifier is also present plus one or more calls are "await"ed

Answer (score 0):

Change your metod  header

```
 public async Task Handle(CreateCompletedActCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
....your code
}
```